# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS freezing frequently

Tags: nvidia

I'm brand new to Linux and am having a very hard time troubleshooting this problem.  Every so often my screen will freeze and I can't do anything but move the mouse around.  I can see the mouse cursor moving around, but I can't click on anything.  The keyboard seems to work for 1 shortcut I found " Alt + Print Screen + R E I S U B ".

It happens every time when I try to open the Amazon app on my sidebar.  It also seems to happen randomly other times like when using the Reddit app occasionally.  I literally just installed Ubuntu within the last 2 hours or so.

> i5 2500K
>
> GSkills Ripjaw 1600Mhz 2 x 4GBs
>
> EVGA GTX 570 Superclocked
>
> ASUS P8P67 Pro Motherboard
>
> Razer Lachesis Mouse
>
> Logitech K350 Wireless Keyboard
>
> 1 Samsung 840 Pro 120GB SSD with Windows 7 64bit
>
> 1st WD Caviar Black 1TB for Windows files

2nd WD Caviar Black 1TB:

```
-500MB Boot Partition set as Primary, Ext4

-200GB Root Partition set as Primary, Ext4

-10GB Swap set as Primary
```

I set Location for the new partition to "Beginning" for all 3 partitions.

The rest of the 1TB drive holding Ubuntu has nothing on it and is just "free space".

I've got 2 monitors hooked up to my GPU; ASUS 23.6" 1080p monitor by DVI and 40" Sony television by HDMI

Comment: Ok, let's see if we can narrow things down a bit. Try running through System Testing (System->Administration->System Testing) a few times; see if it crashes at any consistent point during those tests.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I ran the System Testing and just clicked the "default" profile.

It got to 78% and the my computer crashed completely (as if it had turned off).  It automatically restarted and came back up to the system tester.  The mouse worked for a few seconds but then froze and was unusable.

It stopped on "Running 85 of 109 (7:25) 78% 2013.com.canonical.certification::suspend/suspend_advanced


I tried several keyboard shortcuts which did not work (Alt + F2, Cntrl + Alt + T).  I waited about 10 minutes and tried the Alt + Print Screen + R E I S U B, which restarted my system.

Comment: When I returned I was greeted with a notice saying there was an error with a program, as well as a prompt saying the system suffered a critical error (or something similar).  I didn't actually get a chance to look at it because when I clicked "report" it closed the window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your freezing problem may be caused by an issue with your EVGA GTX 570 graphics card. Nothing in your graphical interface responds is often caused by an issue with your graphics processor, for example a missing graphics driver. Unplug the HDMI cable to your Sony television while you are troubleshooting the problem. Then you can reconnect the television after your operating system is working correctly.

1. Open the Additional Drivers utility (Dash -> Additional Drivers), and select the latest Nvidia driver, version 331 (proprietary, tested). Click the **Apply Changes** button to install it and reboot the computer to enable it.
2. Make a note of the superclocked/overclocked settings of your graphics card for backup/restore purposes. Remove the Superclocked/overclocked settings from your graphics card and select its normal settings instead.

Comment: Had the same problem with a GTX 580, this worked perfectly.

Comment: Reposting of a comment by Jorge: It worked for me as well, NVIDIA GT540M, everything works smoothly now although I couldn't find the Overclock settings, but yeah works fine now. Many thanks.